# How to fix Perforce to git migration clone issue

Tags: git, github, perforce

[image]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: I can imagine several possible causes: `git p4` does not work on Windows. `git p4` does not work with UNC paths (``//Mercury`` is a network path). The user cache could not be created or does not exist in your home directory (`~/.gitp4-usercache.txt`). The latter being what the error message in your screenshot shows.

Comment: How to fix this issue

Comment: first you need to identify what the exact issue is. Try running it in a Linux VM. Copy the remote Perforce directory to a local directory first and clone from there. Check if the usercache file exists and can be created by the Git process. Check if there are any users with invalid names in your Perforce repository.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like you have a Perforce server in non-Unicode mode where one of the user names is invalid UTF8.  If the Perforce server is set to run in Unicode mode, it makes everyone define a character set so it can normalize input to UTF8, but if it's in ASCII mode it just accepts whatever high-ASCII characters you throw at it and returns them unaltered.  If you run through one of the Perforce KB articles on converting a server to Unicode mode I expect that'll fix it, since that'll include a process to normalize/convert non-ASCII checkpoint data.

Comment: @Shiva which python version are you running? I ran into a similar issue trying to use git-p4 on python 3.10. I installed python 2.7 and I was able to get git-p4 to work. Note: I had to delete the old .gitp4-usercache.txt file (that I had created manually).

Answer (score 1):

@Shiva You may need to check p4 environment variables. Type below

> p4 set

You may get character settings.

> P4_host:port_CHARSET=auto

Please try to change utf8 by below command.

> p4 set P4_host:port_CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I tried this and got this error:
 failure accessing depot: p4 error: Unicode clients require a unicode enabled server